# Error using google objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

i am getting error while using objectify.
Actually i am using it in a very simple spring based application, but not getting the proper way to do the same.
to keep it simple, i am not using any service/dao layer.

Model:

```
package com.tut.yudi.model;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

//import java.util.Date;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private long subjectId;

  @Id
    @Index
    private String subjectName;
    private int subjectRank;
    private char status;

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }
    public int getSubjectRank() {
        return subjectRank;
    }
    public void setSubjectRank(int subjectRank) {
        this.subjectRank = subjectRank;
    }
    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

OfyService class:

```
package com.tut.yudi.common.dao;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.tut.yudi.model.Subject;

public class OfyService {
    static {
        factory().register(Subject.class);
        //ObjectifyService.register(Subject.class); --also doesn't work
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
    package com.tut.yudi.controller;

import static com.tut.yudi.common.dao.OfyService.ofy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.tut.yudi.controller.Hello;
import com.tut.yudi.model.Subject;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Controller
public class Hello
{
   protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Hello.class.getName());

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String home()
   {
      //sop();
      return "a";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
   public String hello()
   {
      //sop();

      //some comment

      Subject subject = new Subject();
      subject.setSubjectName("JAVA");
      subject.setSubjectRank(1);
      subject.setStatus('A');
      System.out.println("Model object created...");

      //some coment
      ofy().save().entity(subject).now();
      System.out.println("object created....");
      return "b";
   }

}
```

Here are the logs :

```
Dec 24, 2013 9:15:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4/app/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Dec 24, 2013 9:15:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4/app/WEB-INF/web.xml
Dec 24, 2013 9:15:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4/appengine-java-sdk/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4/app/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
Dec 24, 2013 9:15:58 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Dec 24, 2013 9:15:59 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader checkWorkingDirectory
WARNING: Your working directory, (/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4) is not equal to your 
web application root (/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-g7u2pbf8emc4gvmc-0-df6c037b5f628879778de0427da1f7e4/app)
You will not be able to access files from your working directory on the production server.

Dec 24, 2013 9:15:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:27 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:36886
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:36886/
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:36886/_ah/admin
Dec 24, 2013 9:16:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Dec 24, 2013 9:17:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /hello
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.tut.yudi.controller.Hello.hello(Hello.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.isAssignableFrom(TypeUtils.java:179)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NumberTranslatorFactory.create(NumberTranslatorFactory.java:25)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NumberTranslatorFactory.create(NumberTranslatorFactory.java:18)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.(ClassTranslator.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityClassTranslator.(EntityClassTranslator.java:46)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.(Transmog.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.register(Registrar.java:74)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.register(ObjectifyFactory.java:180)
    at com.tut.yudi.common.dao.OfyService.(OfyService.java:10)
    ... 58 more
Dec 24, 2013 9:17:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.isAssignableFrom(TypeUtils.java:179)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NumberTranslatorFactory.create(NumberTranslatorFactory.java:25)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.NumberTranslatorFactory.create(NumberTranslatorFactory.java:18)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.(ClassTranslator.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityClassTranslator.(EntityClassTranslator.java:46)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.(Transmog.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.register(Registrar.java:74)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.register(ObjectifyFactory.java:180)
    at com.tut.yudi.common.dao.OfyService.(OfyService.java:10)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.tut.yudi.controller.Hello.hello(Hello.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you should check:

1. The exception is related to Objectify's handling of primitive types in your Subject entity so I'd change to use Integer and Character (instead of char and int) in that class.  I didn't manage to reproduce it so maybe it's a bug that was fixed or some other interaction.
2. Both @Id and @Index on Subject.subjectName seems not needed?

Comment: Thnku so much.......
The problem was of primitive types in your Subject entity so I'd change to use Integer and Character (instead of char and int) in that class

Answer (score 0):

ETOOMUCHCOMPLEXITY: the layers of abstraction added by the frameworks cause the error information in the stack trace to not correlate with your source code.  Build the tiniest new application that works.  Gradually add and test pieces  of your application until it breaks, then revert to what worked and try something else.

The earliest mention of your source code in the stack trace is Hello.java line 38.  Counting them, line 38 is the end of file!  It probably means the Hello class as a whole looks good but is failing to initialize.  Since the Hello class itself is very simple, the fault is most likely in its relationship to other things it depends on.